# Action on filtered objects QGIS

Tags: qgis, rule-based, actions

I have got a point layer with about 1000 points. These point has a rule based symbology. So far so common.
In this layer I have also some actions implemented. If I unselect some rules, that only the objects of one rule are displayed. In my case ther are just 10 left. When I want to activate an action I click on an object, but it offers me several objects even those which are not displayed.

Is this a bug or is there a setting which I can set just to make a action to shown objects.